# how can i display a image on button which is presented on UINavigationController iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i display a image on button which is presented on UINavigationController iphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean the back button that is displaying on the Navigation Bar 
you can do

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
barBtnItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=barBtnItem;
[barBtnItem release];
```

Put this code in the Previous page's `viewDidLoad` method or anywhere else before

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

this line

Comment: We also customize UIBarButtonItem at design time, there are a lot of facilities given by apple if you check property of UIBarButtonItem.